# Stream Audio Files using Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, stream, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, emulation

I've setup Raspberry Pi O/S on Oracle Virtual Box.
I want to know whether if its possible to stream an audio file using this emulated Raspberry Pi through a URL or current machine IP to an outside custom application. If so, please let me know how.

Comment: What is an RSP please? And an APP?

Comment: Hi Mark, RSP is the short-form for Raspberry Pi. and I've developed a custom app to listen the audio stream which plays by the Raspberry URL or IP which im mentioned above. Right now i want to know whether if its possible to do it like that.